# Gimp Image->Guides menu item disappeared

Tags: menuitem, gimp

I wanted to use the guides in Gimp but I cannot find it at their traditional place.

The Image menu contains all the usual items (Duplicate, Mode, ..., Configure Grid, Image Properties), apart from the Guides which is supposed to be right above the Configure Grid.

How can I get this menu item back?

It is Windows 7 and Gimp 2.8.22.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution in Gimp to change the content of the menus so I decided to reinstall Gimp. That is, I used the official Add/Remove Programs from the Control Panel to delete it and then I executed the installer.

It did not solve the problem, ie. the Image->Guides menu item was still missing.

So, I

- uninstalled Gimp again
- I used regedit.exe to remove all the references to Gimp (there were some so the uninstall was not totally clean)
- I deleted the folder called `.gimp-2.8` from the `C:\Users\<username>\` directory (it was still there so the uninstall did not do a perfect job).
- then I installed it again.

This solved the problem so it seems that the registry or the `.gimp-2.8` folder got corrupted.

Comment: ... and by deleting everything you removed any chance of researching what exactly had gone wrong :(

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did. I googled for whether anybody else had a similar problem but it did not seem a general or frequent issue so I did not expect anybody would investigate it in more details. Otherwise I would have saved all the relevant information. Since my question, I experienced other severe issues which suggest a file system corruption. So maybe it was not even gimp's fault.